# Почему не устанавливается глобально NODEJS модуль на Debian?

Tags: linux, node.js, debian, node-modules

Здравствуйте. Ноду устанавливал вот так:

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs`

Обновлял npm так:

`npm install npm@latest -g`

Модуль устанавливал вот так:

`npm install express -g`

Создал в корне файл test.js, в котором попросил ноду использовать (require) модуль express. Далее пытался выполнить файл командой node test, но нода сказала, что модуля express она найти не может:

`Error: Cannot find module 'express'`

Comment: Модуль express глобально устанавливали ещё, страшно сказать, в третьей версии. Но есть ещё люди, придерживающиеся традиционных взглядов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте переменную окружения **NODE_PATH**, что указать, где искать модули

```
export NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/node_modules
```